# Logo not showing correctly in IE6>

Tags: internet-explorer, graphical-logo, iepngfix

I just finished my website. I wanted to test how it will handle cross browsers (Chrome, IE, FF).

But the logo does not show properly in IE6 and IE5. It has a dark green background instead of transparent.

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: +1 for hating IE - consider posting your css/inline code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IE6 does not handle transparency, the only way would be to have a version of the image with the background instead of transparency. Alternately just have white background.

Answer (score 2):

Better late than never...

It sounds like you are using a PNG with alpha-channel transparency.
You can enable alpha-channel support in IE5.5 and IE6 using [PNG Fix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/).
I use it on a number of websites with no problems.